# Not working previous page function in android old version like jelly bean ,kitkat android ,its works only lollipop version

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

This is a android application, using in Java script and HTML using sqlite data base

I put one go back to previous page function in my code its working only lollipop android version,

1. jelly bean
2. kitkat android

   this two version am also checked but its not working
   I try different functions

   - window.history.back();
   - history.go(-1);

   > function back()
   >    {
   >     window.history.back();
   >    }

Answer (score 1):

Well it certainly comes from the Chrome version used for the webview.

I strongly recommend you to use Crosswalk to avoid these kind of differences between Android versions (it's not going to be the only difference you will encounter).

Here is an article explaining the benefits of Crosswalk and how to Install it (it alos works for non-Ionic apps): http://geeklearning.io/boost-your-ionic-app-performance/

Hope this helps.